# Convert SQL datetime to string or Date object

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, datetime, knockout.js

I'm trying to get this SQL datetime (yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ) to be somewhat readable. (perhaps yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm)

Now it displays like this:

> 2011-10-28T11:03:52Z

I'm really confused on how to display it like this

> 2011-10-28 11:03

I got this html snippet.

```html
<tbody bgcolor="#eef2f7">
 <!-- ko foreach: $data -->
  <tr>
     <td class="messageCell" style="text-align:right;">
         <label data-bind="text: $data.updated_time"></label>
     </td>
  </tr>
 <!-- /ko -->
</tbody>
```

I got this javascript

```
GET('<!--%root%-->/API/item,
        function (items, textStatus, request) {
            var invoiceeModel =
                contracts.map(function (data) {
                    return {
                        updated_time: ko.observable(data.updated_time)
                    };
        });
```

Pointers, tips and code-snippets are warmly welcome!

Comment: If you are using JS to get the data from DB you can use moment.js for date manipulation

Comment: @SubliemeSiem I want to convert datetime to a string or a js Date object. Not the other way around.

Comment: @SubliemeSiem I'm really sorry, i figured it out! I read your link completely wrong first time. Problem was solved thanks to you!

Comment: @Awots Good to hear!